# Magento 2 : upgrade

Tags: magento2

How to upgrade `magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.5` ? Open source

Can you please advice on steps on upgrading magento 2 ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.4.5 version is not released.

https://devdocs.magento.com/release/released-versions.html